# How do I group by two columns and then count the occurrences of each unique value in a third column for each of the groupings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a unique identifier that I want to group by ["EMID"] along with a date column ["DateNew"]. Then I would like to count the number of times each value in BRalpha occurs for each grouping.

Data Set:

| EMID | DateNew | BRalpha |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SIM10001 | 2016-06-01 | LUMB |
| SIM10001 | 2016-06-01 | LUMB |
| SIM10001 | 2016-07-01 | LUMB |
| SIM10001 | 2016-07-01 | THOR |
| SIM10002 | 2016-02-01 | NSPC |
| SIM10002 | 2016-02-01 | NSPC |
| SIM10002 | 2016-02-01 | NSPC |
| SIM10002 | 2016-02-01 | NSPC |
| SIM10002 | 2016-02-01 | NSPC |
| SIM10003 | 2017-03-01 | ANFT |
| SIM10003 | 2017-03-01 | ANFT |

Desired output:

| EMID | DateNew | Count_LUMB | Count_THOR | Count_NSPC | Count_ANFT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SIM10001 | 2016-06-01 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| SIM10001 | 2016-07-01 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| SIM10002 | 2016-02-01 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 0 |
| SIM10003 | 2017-03-01 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

```
print(
    df.groupby(["EMID", "DateNew", "BRalpha"])
    .size()
    .unstack()
    .fillna(0)
    .astype(int)
    .add_prefix("count_")
    .reset_index()
)
```

Prints:

```
BRalpha      EMID     DateNew  count_ANFT  count_LUMB  count_NSPC  count_THOR
0        SIM10001  2016-06-01           0           2           0           0
1        SIM10001  2016-07-01           0           1           0           1
2        SIM10002  2016-02-01           0           0           5           0
3        SIM10003  2017-03-01           2           0           0           0
```